# Повторение счетчика каждые 10 секунд

Tags: javascript

```
var countdown = $('#timer'),
    startFrom = 10,
    timer;
function startCountdown(){
    countdown.show();
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        countdown.text(startFrom--);
        if(startFrom <= 0) clearInterval(timer);
    },1000);
}
```

Как сделать так, что бы данный код повторялся по своему истечению (10 секунд), ну то есть зациклить надо его
Пробовал через `setInterval(startCountdown, 10000);` но время уходит в минус [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно заново присваивать `startFrom` значение `10`

```js
var countdown = $('#timer'),
    startFrom = 10,
    timer;
function startCountdown(){
    countdown.show();
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        countdown.text(startFrom--);
        if(startFrom < 0){
          clearInterval(timer); 
          startFrom = 10; 
          startCountdown()
        };
    },1000);
};
$(function() {
  startCountdown()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Ну так пытаюсь его зациклить, что бы он повторялся по истечению, но время вместо этого в минус уходит

Comment: @Satont, нужно, что бы время уходило и время возвращалось в 10 сек и опять отнималось?

Comment: да, именно это и надо

Comment: @Satont, смотрите ответ. Я переделал

Comment: Работает. Ещё вопрос, почему он вызывается с такой видимой задержкой? 1-2 секунды

Comment: @Satont, сам таймер изначально? Или уже, когда второй раз запускается?

Comment: @Satont, если я не ошибаюсь лучше использовать setTimout, тут написано в чем разница https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо